# Download manager crashes on On DOWNLOAD COMPLETE

Tags: android, file, download, uri, download-manager

This is my broadcast receiver:

```
 BroadcastReceiver broadcast = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE.equals(action)) {
            dwnId = intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, 0);
            Cursor c = DownloadManagerWrapper.getInstance(getActivity()).getDownloadManager().query(new DownloadManager.Query().setFilterById(dwnId));
            c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS));
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ERROR!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
};
```

On my onCreateView i register it:

```
(getActivity()).registerReceiver(broadcast, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
```

This is how my DownloadManagerWrapper looks like:

```
public class DownloadManagerWrapper {
private static final String DOWNLOAD_SERVICE = "download";

private DownloadManager mgr;

private static DownloadManagerWrapper i;

private DownloadManagerWrapper(Context c) {
    mgr = (DownloadManager) c.getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
}

public static DownloadManagerWrapper getInstance(Context c) {
    if (i == null) {
        i = new DownloadManagerWrapper(c);
    }
    return i;
}

public DownloadManager getDownloadManager() {
    return mgr;
}

}
```

This is what i do that makes it FC:

```
 if(Util.hasNetworkConnection(ctx)){
        Uri destination = Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/media/video.mp4");
        DownloadManagerWrapper.getInstance(ctx).getDownloadManager().enqueue(new DownloadManager.Request(uri).setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE).setAllowedOverRoaming(false).setDestinationUri(destination));
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(ctx, "No Internet Available!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

I get this error:

```
02-14 15:57:03.488: E/AndroidRuntime(4987): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-14 15:57:03.488: E/AndroidRuntime(4987): java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE flg=0x10 pkg=com.Red.medicalpaint (has extras) } in com.Red.Fragments.AppLibraryFragment$1@41a1f998
02-14 15:57:03.488: E/AndroidRuntime(4987):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:765)
02-14 15:57:03.488: E/AndroidRuntime(4987):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
02-14 15:57:03.488: E/AndroidRuntime(4987):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-14 15:57:03.488: E/AndroidRuntime(4987):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-14 15:57:03.488: E/AndroidRuntime(4987):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4978)
02-14 15:57:03.488: E/AndroidRuntime(4987):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/media/video.mp4" to see if it returns the correct route?

Comment: yes, and i had to ad an "file://". Now it's correct. but i have another problem. i will now edit my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commenting this line, made it work:

c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS));